# Screen Reader reporting of *valid* input after user change

Tags: javascript, forms, accessibility, screen-readers

I feel that I'm being driven crazy by this question CONSTANTLY and I'm looking for more definitive answers to the idea as I can't find any information regarding this idea.

Normally a non-sighted user is (should be) presented with an accessible error when they have entered invalid information into a form. No problems there.

Is there any methodology or precedent to report form (field) validity from a previously invalid field to a non-sighted user when it becomes valid?

I know the former is typically handled by leveraging a javascript construct to manipulate the `aria-invalid` property to present an appropriate notification to the non-sighted user upon error, then removing that once the error has been resolved. Is the success of that only just dependent on the field no longer rendering an error or should there be an explicit notification to inform a non-sighted user that, in fact, "yes the field is valid"?

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

When `aria-invalid` changes to false most screen readers will announce this, worst case they will announce it when the input is focused again.

There is nothing else you need to do to tell a screen reader user a field is valid as this is expected behaviour.

### Long Answer

You do not need to do anything special here, but implementing `aria-invalid` in the correct way is important.

The field should start without the attribute, the last thing you want is every field saying it is invalid when it is empty on page load as this can cause confusion.

Additionally do not use this on **required** fields to indicate they need to be filled in as that is what the `required` attribute is for!

Then as the user types you update the value accordingly (so add it on first key press and then change it when the field becomes valid, `aria-invalid="true"` to `aria-invalid="false"` when correct).

**Most screen readers will announce changes to `aria-invalid` instantly, worst case they will announce it when the field receives focus.**

The key to accessibility is expected behaviour. It is expected behaviour for some screen reader users to refocus a field to check validity if their screen reader does not announce the `aria-invalid` change live. Sometimes you can make accessibility worse by trying to fix something like this as users get confused.

What is more important is making sure there are easy ways to know what errors there are on a form when a user tries to submit it and making it easy to identify and navigate to fields that need correcting.

I have tried not to stray from the question in hand but make sure you use techniques such as:

- intercepting `onsubmit` on a form rather than intercepting the submit button key press when there are errors (as keyboard users will probably submit using <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- using `aria-decribedby` to provide additional information (and also more meaningful error notifications on a field)
- placing all errors at the top of the form and the number of errors
- using `role="alert"` or `aria-live` to announce the errors in the first place and explain what needs to be fixed.

### If you really want to announce fields are valid

The above advice covers 99% of scenarios but I am sure there is an edge case somewhere that needs you to announce when a field is valid live.

As such you should use an `aria-live` region and update it with the current field validity (with some throttling so it doesn't flood the announce queue).

I would go for something like "first name - error - too short" and change it to "first name - correct" or "first name - valid".

As I said I cannot think of a scenario where this would be needed but that is how you *could* handle this.